# Argument of type 'firebase.default.auth.Auth' is not assignable to parameter of type useAuthState

Tags: typescript, firebase

I'm trying to call the useAuthState hook from the react-firebase-hooks npm package but I'm getting the following error:

```
Argument of type 'firebase.default.auth.Auth' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("C:/path/1/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth-public").Auth'.
  Types of property 'setPersistence' are incompatible.
    Type '(persistence: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(persistence: Persistence) => Promise<void>'.
      Types of parameters 'persistence' and 'persistence' are incompatible.
        Type 'Persistence' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

The relevant code is as follows in my hooks.ts file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'

export function useUserData() {
const [user] = useAuthState(firebase.auth())
                              ^^^^^^^^^ here is the error
}
```

I think I'm supposed to typecast in some capacity and use angle brackets like so `useAuthState<someDataType>(firebase.auth))` but I'm not sure what type will aid the error.

Comment: I seem to be getting the same error. I'm wondering if `react-firebase-hooks` needs an update to handle a breaking change in `firebase` package. What versions are you using? I have the following: `"react-firebase-hooks": "^4.0.1", "firebase": "^9.6.1"`

Comment: I'm using `react-firebase-hooks": "4.0.1", "firebase": "10.0.1".` If you find anything that solves this problem let me know, my band-aid solution was to change the file extension to 'js' from 'ts' and the type problem.

Comment: I think a better band aid solution might be to just cast `firebase.auth()` as `any` like so: `const [user] = useAuthState(auth as any);`. That way you can keep using TS in your file.